# Dynamic scale Sierpinski Triangle

Tags: java, recursion, graphics, paintcomponent

For class I have been asked to make a Sierpinski Triangle drawer which will dynamically rescale as the user changes the window size, by recursively subdividing a square region of the panel until int is 1x1 pixel, then coloring that pixel. I think that I'm nearly there, but since my understanding of object oriented programming is fuzzy at best, I'm not entirely clear about how to actually draw the individual pixels. The paintComponent method is what will be called each time the window is resized correct? as such i need it to call sierMaker and create the triangle, but if sierMaker then calls paintsComponent to draw the pixels wont it enter an infinite loop? I have no doubt that I'm missing something obvious here, would appreciate some help with figuring out what my error(s) are though. Be merciful to a newbie?

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.geom.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class Triangle extends JPanel {

        public int getsize(){
            int wi = this.getWidth();
            int he = this.getHeight();
            int size = 0;

            if (wi <= he) {
                size = wi;
            } else {
                size = he; }

            return size;
        }

        public void sierMaker(int x, int y, int side) {


                //if is 1x1, draw it, else subdivide(WIP)
                if (side == 1) {
                    //create rectangle object (x,y,side,side), and pass it to paintComponent. This is where I need help.


                } else {
                //was too large, break into 3 portions and check again
                    sierMaker(x/2, y, side/2);
                    sierMaker(x,y/2,side/2);
                    sierMaker(x/2,y/2,side/2);
                }   
        }

        //paintComponent method to draw individual pixels once input sqare is subdived into small enough portions by recursion
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

                sierMaker(0,0,getsize());
            }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            //set initial size of panel to monitor resolution
            Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

            //initalize JFrame
            JFrame display = new JFrame();
            display.setTitle("Sierpinski Triangles");
            display.setBounds(0,0,screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
            display.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
            Triangle panel = new Triangle();
            display.add(panel);
            display.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't call the `paintComponent()`. You should pass the `Graphics` object that is handed to `paintComponent()` to the `sierMaker` for it to be able to draw.

Comment: I see, I had been so busy trying to pass something **into** `paintComponent` that i never thought to pass something **out**. thanks, that seems to have fixed it.